# How can i access this hash using angular 2

Tags: javascript

```
{"id":"20902a99-fa74-4ac7-97b5-1c50d59f536b",
 "name":"User 1 Staff Lopperne",
 "groupsPostRights":{
        "0":{"id":"04b01fac-a285-4596-b78b-2f64e703678e","institutionId":"7c7b10d5-68fb-4768-8c5a-fdf3573460c4"
,"name":"Alle","subtitle":null,"parentId":null,"type":"main"},
        "1":{"id":"7f8541c9-dbe3-495d-ba02-e73e4e74e7f4","institutionId":"7c7b10d5-68fb-4768-8c5a-fdf3573460c4","name":"Personale","subtitle":null,"parentId":null,"type":"staff"},
        "3":{"id":"b07ef269-df60-4f58-b66e-248c12f9c8ac","institutionId":"7c7b10d5-68fb-4768-8c5a-fdf3573460c4"
                ,"name":"Lopperne (Personale)","subtitle":null,"parentId":"053c8681-70b3-40f9-9a7b-a946028ef7b8","type"
                :"staff"},
        "4":{"id":"d5368df8-d981-4030-b217-1415e87ccabe","institutionId":"7c7b10d5-68fb-4768-8c5a-fdf3573460c4"
                ,"name":"Lopperne (For\u00e6ldre)","subtitle":null,"parentId":"053c8681-70b3-40f9-9a7b-a946028ef7b8"
                ,"type":"parents"}},
    "isManagerAt":[]}
```

Please help me to fetch **"groupsPostRights"** in hash

Comment: What do you mean by hash?Do you want this json into some component?

Comment: `console.log(hash['groupsPostRights'])` simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general javascript question. You simply need to parse the JSON string.

```
var json = '{"id":"20902a99-fa74-4ac7-97b5-1c50d59f536b", "name":"User 1 Staff Lopperne", "groupsPostRights":{ "0":{"id":"04b01fac-a285-4596-b78b-2f64e703678e","institutionId":"7c7b10d5-68fb-4768-8c5a-fdf3573460c4" ,"name":"Alle","subtitle":null,"parentId":null,"type":"main"}, "1":{"id":"7f8541c9-dbe3-495d-ba02-e73e4e74e7f4","institutionId":"7c7b10d5-68fb-4768-8c5a-fdf3573460c4","name":"Personale","subtitle":null,"parentId":null,"type":"staff"}, "3":{"id":"b07ef269-df60-4f58-b66e-248c12f9c8ac","institutionId":"7c7b10d5-68fb-4768-8c5a-fdf3573460c4" ,"name":"Lopperne (Personale)","subtitle":null,"parentId":"053c8681-70b3-40f9-9a7b-a946028ef7b8","type" :"staff"}, "4":{"id":"d5368df8-d981-4030-b217-1415e87ccabe","institutionId":"7c7b10d5-68fb-4768-8c5a-fdf3573460c4" ,"name":"Lopperne (For\u00e6ldre)","subtitle":null,"parentId":"053c8681-70b3-40f9-9a7b-a946028ef7b8" ,"type":"parents"}}, "isManagerAt":[]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var rights = obj.groupsPostRights;
```